# Debian USB installation

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I am trying to install Debian 9 in a computer which doesn't have a DVD drive, which means that I have to install it through USB. I have tried several methods that I found on the Internet such as using Rufus, UNetbootin and directly copy the files through the `dd` command.

The problem is that in every attempt, either the boot path is not found or the installation guide thinks that I'm using a DVD. I have a workaround I found to mount the usb directory as `/cdrom` but it doesn't let me.

Any ideas on what I should do now?

Comment: It works for me with Debian iso files to **clone** from the iso file to the USB pendrive. You can do it in linux with [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) or **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` and in Windows with [**Win32 Disk Imager**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)

Comment: You say "copy the files through `dd`".  You should only be copying *one* file: the `.iso`.  Also make sure you are copying onto a device not a partition.  eg: `dd if=debian-9.8.0-amd64-netinst.iso of=/dev/sdb` That's `/dev/sdb` not `/dev/sdb1`.  When you are finished, remember to call `sync`.  It shouldn't have cached anything but you might as well be certain.

Comment: @GAD3R, Thank you! I'm using this link:

Comment: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.8.0-amd64-netinst.iso

Comment: By the way the reason it's so simple to copy the iso on a CD (or DVD) *or* on an USB key, is because it's an hybrid image, which can behave both as a bootable CD and a bootable disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update. I used the mini.iso image and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [win32diskimager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) as described in the [USB Memory Stick Booting Installation Guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.html#usb-copy-isohybrid). This way the "cdrom" is found by the debian setup. Just be careful to select the correct target device when writing the iso.